# Adding Pygame to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, path, pygame, pythonpath

- Windows 8 64 bit
- Python 3.4.3
- Pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.4

I'm in the process of trying to install Pygame now. This computer has two hard-drives, and I'm not sure if that means anything, but when I try and install Pygame it defaults to my `D:\` drive. Python itself is installed on my `C:\` drive however. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM5SJ.png) is what I see when I try to install Pygame and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7njoT.png) is what I think I should see when I install it (right?). That is a screenshot from a video tutorial I was following.

So, I've copied all the files from the `pygame` folder to where it should installed, which are `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages` and `C:\Python34\include`. Instead of getting the usual import error, I now get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfHIq.png). I've looked at a bunch of similar problems and they all said that the problem probably is the `PYTHONPATH`. So I've gone to the environment variables > system variables and clicked `New`.  `Variable name = PYTHONPATH` and `Variable_Value = C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pygame;` Is this right?

When I type `import sys` --> `print (sys.path)`, pygame does [show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNTI6.png), but I still get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problem when installing pygame, Windows 8.1 wouldn't recognise MinGW system variable, and leading to this pygame was never found.

What solved problem for me is http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Here you can find unofficial wheels for many packages that won't install for varoius reasons or simply don't work too well.

You simply need pip with version >= 6. Install the one with cp34, it is corresponding with CPython 3.4.

Comment: Thank you, but I finally found the problem! I've been installing pygame properly, but the wrong version. I was installing 32 bit for the past few days wondering why it didn't work. I needed to install the 64 bit, which was a whl file. I tried avoiding .whl files because pip itself is a mess for me, but I realized you can unzip them with 7zip. I extracted it to the desktop and copied it into `site-packages`. Once I did this, I could `import pygame` and `print (pygame.ver)` successfully. I honestly didn't think the 32/64 bit would matter but it did in this case